# Joining by id variable and date in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables in postgreSQL that I am attempting to join by `id`.

I would like the output to show the the year and month of the `created_at` column of `promo_code_uses` (the as date query works by itself)  as well as all of the columns in `promo_codes`.  However I get an error when I try the following query:

```
select date_trunc('month',created_at)::date as date, id as id
from promo_code_uses
left join promo_codes 
on promo_code_uses.id = promo_codes.id
order by date DESC;


ERROR:  column reference "created_at" is ambiguous
LINE 1: select date_trunc('month',created_at)::date as date, id as i..
```

Any idea why the error might be occurring at the date_trunc function?

This query, for example, works, but as soon as I try a left join with a different table there is a problem:

```
select date_trunc('month',created_at)::date as date , id as id 
from promo_code_uses
order by date DESC;
```

Comment: sounds like created_at is a standard field in many of your tables.  you need to qualify the field with the table name.

Comment: `select date_trunc('month',promo_code_uses.created_at)::date as date, id as id
    from promo_code_uses
    left join promo_codes 
    on promo_code_uses.id = promo_codes.id
    order by date DESC;
`

Comment: how would one do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`promo_codes` and `promo_code_uses` both have `create_at` field, prefix with correct table name.

```
select date_trunc('month',promo_code_uses.created_at)::date as date , id as id 
from promo_code_uses
order by date DESC;
```